# Deploy on appstore, but not for iPod4th gen

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have a game that is quite CPU intensive. It works well on all devices (from iPhone4+) but it's very laggy on iPod 4th generation. 
I'd like to release it on the appstore, and make sure that iPod4 users cannot download it, as they will probably be very disapointed. 
The only solution I can think of so far, is to make the app iOS7 only, as iPod4 cannot upgrade to iOS7, but I'd like to avoid that.
Do you have any other solution?
Thanks.

Comment: You can put the magnetometer as a requirement.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll investigate that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've tried that, but on my binary details, on iTunesConnect, it still says : 
Device Family :   iPhone / iPod Touch, iPad
Any idea on how to do fix that?

Comment: it will say that anyway, but any device without magnetometer (i.e. ipod touch 4th generation) shouldn't even see the app in the store